# Displaying multiple slider values to users

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating a form with sliders for answers. I need to be able to show users their current selection. My issue is that this only works for the last question, so the code is functional but doesn't allow any room for expansion.

Try the sliders below and notice that only one of them displays the `<span>` value and the rest don't.

```html
<input type="range" min="1" max="10" value="0" class="slider" id="question1">
<span id="question1score"></span>
<br><br>
<input type="range" min="1" max="10" value="0" class="slider" id="question2">
<span id="question2score"></span>
<br><br>
<input type="range" min="1" max="10" value="0" class="slider" id="question3">
<span id="question3score"></span>
<br><br>
<input type="range" min="1" max="10" value="0" class="slider" id="question4">
<span id="question4score"></span>

<script>
var slider = document.getElementById("question1");
var output = document.getElementById("question1score");
var slider = document.getElementById("question2");
var output = document.getElementById("question2score");
var slider = document.getElementById("question3");
var output = document.getElementById("question3score");
var slider = document.getElementById("question4");
var output = document.getElementById("question4score");
output.innerHTML = slider.value;

slider.oninput = function() {
  output.innerHTML = this.value;
}
</script>
```

Any tips to get all of these to work properly would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Get all sliders by class name and add event listener to them.

When slider get change show the value to related `span`.

```js
var sliders = document.getElementsByClassName("slider");

for(var i=0; i<(sliders.length); i++) {
  sliders[i].addEventListener('input', function() {
    document.getElementById(this.getAttribute('id')+'score').innerText = this.value;
  });
}
```

```html
<input type="range" min="1" max="10" value="0" class="slider" id="question1">
<span id="question1score"></span>
<br><br>
<input type="range" min="1" max="10" value="0" class="slider" id="question2">
<span id="question2score"></span>
<br><br>
<input type="range" min="1" max="10" value="0" class="slider" id="question3">
<span id="question3score"></span>
<br><br>
<input type="range" min="1" max="10" value="0" class="slider" id="question4">
<span id="question4score"></span>
```

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me.... and I spent the past 4 hours trying all the solutions on stackoverflow until I discovered this one.

Thank you!